# What is the most performant way to structure my multi-language SQLite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, query-performance, sqlperformance

I am buiding a mobile app to search and manage a collection of playing cards (approximately 10,000). Each card has characteristics which are shared among all languages and four language-specific strings: title, effect1, effect2 and character. Only a limited amount of cards have non-NULL effect2 and character (less than 10%). Some cards may be available in some languages but not in others.

I am using SQLite to store the card database locally and use [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to access it (my app is made with Flutter, but I don't think it makes any difference for my question).

My initial idea was to store all the language-agnostic information in a table `cards` and all the language-specific info in a table `card_texts` with one row per pair `(card_id,language)`.

However, dealing with the response that this request produces is annoying because it results in multiple rows per card (one per language), and I would have to reduce this manually in client code.

The reason why I don't only make one table per language and call it a day is that because as some cards exist in some languages and not in some others, I want to be able to fall back to another language if needed. For instance, I might list the cards in French, but if a card was not translated to French get it in English, and if it was not translated to English then get it in Japanese.

My second idea was to have all languages in a single row per card id in `card_texts` so that the result of the JOIN produces only one row per card. To do this I put 33 columns in it (`card_id` + 4 TEXT columns per language). This was more convenient because I could get all the languages for each card and move the "falling back" logic to client code, but I'm not sure that it is very efficient to have a table that large when most of the time I need only one language.

My third idea is to create one table per language, each one having 5 columns (`card_id` + 4 TEXT columns). However I either have to JOIN all these or perform multiple requests if I want to fall back to another language.

Here are the actions I want to be able to perform as efficiently as possible (especially because this is going to run on a mobile phone):

1. Get one card's info + text in my default language + fall back to other languages if the card was not translated, in a given order (e.g. try French, then English, then Japanese)
2. Do the same thing for multiple cards (one request to get all cards matching a certain criteria)
3. Be able to search cards in all languages given some string
4. Ideally, be able to join this with other tables which might have multiple rows for one card (and so I would like to avoid having my number of rows per card multiplied as much as possible)

Given my performance and size constraints (I want this to run on low-end mobile phones, with the database possibly stored on a slow SD card), is it better to have a higher number of columns, to perform more JOINs or to have to perform multiple requests? Is there another solution I haven't thought of?

Comment: @CPerkins I was not saying that the concept of JOINs itself was annoying, just that the way I used it it initially it would create multiple rows per card, which is annoying to deal with because it would repeat most of the data. When it comes to numbers, I have ~10,000 cards and 8 languages, the length of the first and fourth texts are usually around 20 characters long, the second and the third something like 200. I'm not concerned about the capabilities of SQLite but more of users putting my DB on a slow SD card and therefore providing a poor user experience.

Comment: So you would suggest I use one table per language for my two first columns, and one table per language for the two columns that are 90% of the time NULL? And then use JOINs to get all the information?
And also, what about the fallback I would like to implement? Let's say that I make a request which matches 200 cards and I want to display them in French. Let's say that 20 of them were not translated to French, so I fall back to English, and 10 more of them are only available in Japanese. What is the best option: JOIN all languages from the start, or perform multiple requests?

Comment: Since you're using sqflite, have you considered moving all the processing that's awkward or "annoying" in SQL to sqflite?

Comment: @peak the problem is not writing the request, the problem is handling the response that it produces, if I have multiple rows per card in the response because of a join which matches multiple cards in the second table, I have to reduce this manually in the client which I belive should not happen if I find a well-suited database structure. This is why my "initial idea" is not ideal to me. Ideas 2 and 3 produce a single row per card which is more convenient to deal with but I use a 33 columns for text table in solution 2 which I might not always need, and could perform 8 joins in solution 3...

Comment: @CPerkins and peak I have edited my initial post to hopefully clarify my problem